# Add action to "Enter" button on Android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, action, enter

I would like to know how can I add an event/action for pressing the "Enter" button on the keyboard.

"The action would be the same as pressing the Button that I created on my application"

Answer (score 1):

You can use imeOptions attribute to specify an action on your EditText

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/password"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/password_hint"
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:imeOptions="actionLogin" />
```

and then create a listener on your activity/fragment for that action

```
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
password.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_LOGIN) {
        login();
    }
    return false;
}});
```

Comment: But in the code the "enter" only would work if the EditText be used? I want a way that the "enter" do the same activity of the button on my app.

Comment: so how do you open the keyboard in your activity without an EditText?

Comment: Oh,yes, I expressed myself wrong. On the imeOptions I can put the same metod that I put on my button? For both execute the same actions

Comment: Of course. Just add an OnClickListener to your button that calls the same method

Comment: Understood.  Last doubt: I need to write this code on all EditText of my app or just one time and it will work for every EditText?

Comment: You have to write that on all your EditText